# Can I import one or more Subsections from a SASS file?

Tags: css, import, sass

My SASS-generated CSS files are filling up with a bunch of stuff I don't need.  This means my users have to download a much bigger CSS file than they really need.

In most programming languages it is possible to create an import statement like this:

```
from "some_codefile" import Dog, Cat, Fish
```

For a SASS scenario lets assume I have a partial file `_colors.scss`,

It contains:

```
$white: #ffffff;

@mixin black() {
    color: black;
}

.red {
    color: red;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Now I want to import `$white`, `@include black`, and `.red`.  However, I do not use the `.blue` class and do not want to import it since it will just take up space in my CSS file.

I tried:

```
@import "colors.scss" white, black, red;
```

But it just gives syntax errors.

How do I prevent my CSS file from filling up with stuff I do not need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You can however use [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_) in your partials and they will not be rendered unless they are `@extend`ed.

```
$white: #ffffff;

@mixin black {
    color: black;
}

%red {
    color: red;
}

%blue {
    color: blue;
}

.foo {
  @extend %red;
}

.bar {
  @extend black;
}
```